# find maximum height of nested list tags in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to find the maximum height of nested tags. A single list is nested one level deep. Each list inside another list is nested one level deeper. If there are no lists at all in the tree, the height of nesting is 0.

Below is my HTML document:

```
<p>
  <div>Hello:
     <ol>
       <div>World:
         <div>
           <p>
             <div>Tree</div>
           </p>
         </div>
       </div>
     </ol>
  </div>
  <div>Wood</div>
</p>
<p>
  <div>simple list1</div>
</p>
<p>
</p>
```

I have to write a function that can return height of nested lists.

Answer (score 6):

By first finding all the `ul` and `ol` elements and then find all their own ul/ol children (`map` and `find`), the max depth (`length`of children) can be found:

```
function findDepth(){
    return  Math.max.apply(null, $('ul, ol').map((i,l)=> $(l).find('ul, ol').length)) + 1;
}
```

```js
function findDepth(){
 return  Math.max.apply(null, $('ul, ol').map((i,l)=> $(l).find('ul, ol').length)) + 1;
}

console.log(findDepth());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Item:
     <ol>
       <li>Point:
         <div>
           <ul>
             <li>elem1</li>
           </ul>
         </div>
       </li>
     </ol>
  </li>
  <li>elem2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>simple list1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is giving the length or count, not the depth of tree.

`
<ul>
  <li>simple list1</li>
  <ol>nested1 <div /></ol>
  <ol>nested2 <div /></ol>
</ul>

`

Expected is 2 but your solution is giving 3

Answer (score 0):

@david,

Please try the below method for findDepth(). This will return the intensity of depth of nodes.

```
var findDepth = function ( root ) {
    var children = $( root ).children();
    var depth = 0;

    while ( children.length > 0 ) {
        children = children.children();
        depth += 1;
    }

    return depth;
};
```